# Selenium catch popup on close browser

Tags: java, selenium, browser

I'm trying to test that when I close my window a popup shows with a warning message.

I've tried both driver.close() and driver.quit() after making sure I'm on the proper window but this just terminates the process since my popup doesn't show.

I could test it by using the awt Robot and sending alt+f4 but this doesn't seem too reliable.

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: Is the alert showing or not after closing the browser and what browser you are using?

Comment: On chrome and firefox the popup shows after closing the browser. The problem is testing it with selenium. As I said, during the test I now send alt+f4 keys to test it and it seems to work but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I think Selenium is force quitting the browser and hence you are not able to see the pop up. That may be a limitation of selenium.

Comment: @Manu Yes I think this is the case.

Comment: @Fofole Have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `driver.quit()` to close the browser, closing it using the Actions object may work for you. This is another way to close the browser using the keyboard shortcuts.

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL+"w")).perform();
```

Or, if there are multiple tabs opened in driver window:

```
act.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.SHIFT+"w")).perform();
```

Comment: So I've ran into a problem with CI using the AWT robot and tried to use your code and it doesn't work(it doesn't send the keys). Maybe I should find a element in the page to focus it before sending the keys ?

Comment: was it working before? Selecting the element and using actions is similar things and may not solve the issue.

Comment: Well locally I used the awt.robot presskeys and it worked. But on CI machine it won't work with awt so I tried your code and it doesn't work. You are right I tried focusing the window and it still doesn't work.

Comment: That seems to an issue with CI machine then. There maybe no other way of closing the browser.

Comment: New test -> driver.navigate().to("about:"); then sendkeys won't work. Nothing to do with the CI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch into the alert if the alert is displayed accept or dismiss it and then call `driver.quit();`

```
if(driver.switchTo().alert() != null)//switches only if alert is displayed
{
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.dismiss(); // alert.accept();

}
driver.quit();
```

Hope this helps you...kindly get back if it is not working for you

Comment: Hi. The driver.quit() already closes the browser no questions asked .. so it won't even go to that IF. The only way I found out how to do it is send an ALT+F4 keys with the AWT ROBOT which I'm not that comfortable using. Thank you.